# Merge two dynamic columns and keeping there json data structure in kusto?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

```
let OriginalTable = datatable(data1:dynamic, data2:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"name":"Name_1","data":[5,6,7,8]}),
    dynamic({"name":"Name_2","data":[9,10,11,12]})
];
```

I have this table. How is it possible to merge those two columns under one column keeping the outcome as a json object.

I tried concatenating them using strcat with "," but it changes the structure of the column.

The expected result should be the following:

```
{
    "name": "Name_1",
    "data": [
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Name_2",
    "data": [
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12
    ]
}
```

Comment: you may want to clarify what you mean by "merge" by providing the desired output. for example - do you wish "name" to become "names" - an array? and do you wish "data" to be an array with all members from "data1.data" and "data2.data"?

Answer (score 0):

To get output as `Json` document by merging two dynamic columns, use below code:

```sql
let OriginalTable = datatable(data1: dynamic, data2: dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"name":"Name_1","data":[5,6,7,8]}),
    dynamic({"name":"Name_2","data":[9,10,11,12]})
];
OriginalTable
| project data = data1
| union (
    OriginalTable
    | project data = data2
)
| summarize json_data = make_list(pack("name", tostring(data.name), "data", data.data)) 
| project tostring(json_data)
```

The `union` operator in the above code is used for combining both `data1` and `data2` dynamic columns and `summarize` is used for aggregating the resulting rows and `make_list` function is applied to aggregate all rows into a single list. Each item in this list is a JSON object generated using `pack`, which combines the `name` and `data` fields from each row.

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "name":"Name_1",
        "data":[5,6,7,8]
    },
    {
        "name":"Name_2",
        "data":[9,10,11,12]
    }
]
```